# TableName with total rowcount

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a sql query below which I am trying to get a count(*) of all tables

```
select Outer.Table_Name, Column_Name, sub.rowcount
from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns Outer
-- left join (select sub.TableName, count(*) As rowcount from  LeadBase)sub
-- sub.TableName = Outer.Table_Name
where Table_Name  = 'LeadBase' and Column_Name in ('CreatedOn','ModifiedOn')
order by 2
```

But obviously the above won't work because you cant use the tablename in the subquery (commented out bit) , is there anyway to do it so I have the count(*) result along the tableName from the outter query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      SCHEMA_NAME(A.schema_id) + '.' + A.Name, SUM(B.rows) AS 'RowCount'
```

FROM sys.objects A INNER JOIN sys.partitions B ON A.object_id = B.object_id
WHERE A.type = 'U'GROUP BY    A.schema_id, A.Name

Comment: This looks promising, I shall get back to you after playing around with the query

Comment: Hi it works but it multiplying by a lot as sometimes in the partition table, the object_ID appears more than once. May need bring a max() one of the ID's, would you know which to use?

Comment: Then only sum all rows from multiple object_ID in partition table

Comment: This doesn't work either say one table has 100 rows, it has 4x partition, that 100 rows will appear 4 times. Grouping wouldn't work on the max as it still brings back 400 in whatever way you do it, any suggestions on how the SQL should be to prevent that

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort it by getting your idea of looking at the Partition Table

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS [Current Database], sc.name, ta.name TableName,
SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
FROM sys.tables ta
INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE  pa.index_id IN (1,0) and Type = 'U'
GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
ORDER BY SUM(pa.rows) DESC
```